# Detail view not updating when UITableView rows are re-ordered

Tags: ios, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath, nsindexpath

I have a UITableView that pushes to a Detail ViewController. In my tableview, my rows are draggable/re-arrangeable. However, when the rows are switched, the path stays the same when selecting the rows and the Detail View is presented. Example: [TableView Re-order Pic](http://cdn2.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/LongPress.gif)

If I were to switch the "Milk" row with the "Gym" row, then select "Gym", the detail view would still return the details of the milk row.

How do I fix this so that the path of the rows switch appropriately as they do?

**.m :**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self->newArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *theFood = [values objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [theFood valueForKey:@"name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [theFood valueForKey:@"price"];

    return cell;
}



- (IBAction) EditTable:(id)sender
{
    if(self.editing)
    {
        [super setEditing:NO animated:NO];
        [_myTableView setEditing:NO animated:NO];
       // [_myTableView reloadData];
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain];
    }
    else
    {
        [super setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [_myTableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
       // [_myTableView reloadData];
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone];

    }
}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
        if( fromIndexPath == toIndexPath ) {
            return;
        }

    NSDictionary *moveFood = [self->newArray objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [self->newArray removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [self->newArray insertObject:moveFood atIndex:toIndexPath.row];



}



- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailSegue"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        DetailViewController *detailVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        detailVC.detailFood = [values objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
}
```

Comment: What data structure do you use "behind" the TableView.  Can't you just update that and do `reloadData`?

Comment: (Think of a TableView as a "view" of a table.  You manage the table and then have the TableView "view" it.  You don't use the TableView as your data structure.)

Comment: So, update your `values` array and `reloadData`.

Comment: I tried [_myTableView reloadData] at the end of my moveRowAtIndexPath method, it didn't seem to work.. :(

Comment: Did you update `values`?  And are you getting the info for your detail view from `values` (after it's been updated)?  (Your code above is updating `newArray`, but not `values`.)

Comment: I changed my datasource from values to newArray because it's a NSMutableArray. I edited my code so that newArray is now the only datasource.

Comment: I fixed it!! I didn't change my datasource for the detail view from values to newArray after the update as you said! Thank you so much!!! :) @HotLicks

Answer (score 0):

When you switch the rows you should also update your data source. Otherwise when tableView's didSelect method is called it would access the wrong object in your data source array.

So in `–tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` switch the location of the objects that were switched.

Answer (score 0):

Special thanks to @HotLicks for helping me!

The problem was I didn't change my datasource for the detail view from values NSArray to my newArray NSMutableArray after the update in my `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` method!